# Необходимо ограничить кол-во выводимых "рецептов" в запросе

Tags: python, django, api

Сейчас к ViewSet подключена пагинация, которая при GET запросе с параметром ?limit=2 ограничивает количество выводимого result, а необходимо ограничить кол-во "рецептов" в самих результатах.
Пример ниже для понимания:

```
{ 
  "count": 123, 
  "next": "http://example.org/api/users/subscriptions/?page=4", 
  "previous": "http://example.org/api/users/subscriptions/?page=2", 
  "results": [ 
    { 
      "email": "user@example.com", 
      "id": 0, 
      "username": "string", 
      "first_name": "Вася", 
      "last_name": "Пупкин", 
      "is_subscribed": true, 
      "recipes": [     **<-Надо чтоб с помощью ?recipes_limit=2 выводилось опр. кол-во "рецептов"**
        { 
          "id": 0, 
          "name": "string", 
          "image": "http://foodgram.example.org/media/recipes/images/image.jpeg", 
          "cooking_time": 1 
        } 
      ], 
      "recipes_count": 0 
    } 
  ] 
}
```